# Bash - deleting lines that dont start with 2 characters and a space

Tags: bash

I have a text file that has some junk that I need removed. There are some lines that contain 2 characters and a space then other junk words. I need edit the file and leave these two words by themselves. For example

```
aa hello how are you
hey how are you doing
za this is cool
bb

hey be
```

Would be converted to

```
aa
za
bb
```

How can I do this using sed? They only include lowercase letters. Thanks!

Comment: but i didn't find any space after `bb`

Answer (score 2):

Through sed.

```
sed 's/^\([^ ][^ ]\)[[:blank:]].*/\1/' file
```

Through grep.

```
grep -oP '^\S{2}(?=\s)' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk to do this:

```
awk 'length($1)==2{print $1}' file
```

It checks that the length of the first field is two and if so, prints it. It doesn't strictly adhere to your requirement of "two characters followed by a space" but it produces the desired output:

```
aa
bA
bb
```

Answer (score 0):

With grep:

`grep -Eo "^..(\s|$)" filename`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another `sed` option:

```
sed '/^.. /!d;s/^\(..\).*/\1/' file
```